# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith' while makemigrations with manage.py in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7

I am using Django 1.9.13 with python 2.7.5
When i make migrations i get below error.
I checked the database settings, all fine working with other app.
I couldn't figure out the solution.

I am using mysql DB at the backend.
I am using one app that is carried from test environment.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in 
execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site-p 
Packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
self.check()
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 28, in check_all_models
errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1178, in check
errors.extend(cls._check_fields(**kwargs))
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1255, in _check_fields
errors.extend(field.check(**kwargs))
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 925, in check
errors = super(AutoField, self).check(**kwargs)
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 208, in check
errors.extend(self._check_backend_specific_checks(**kwargs))
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 317, in 
_check_backend_specific_checks
return connections[db].validation.check_field(self, **kwargs)
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 18, in check_field
field_type = field.db_type(connection)
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 625, in db_type
return connection.data_types[self.get_internal_type()] % data
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 184, in data_types
if self.features.supports_microsecond_precision:
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 53, in 
supports_microsecond_precision
return self.connection.mysql_version >= (5, 6, 4) and Database.version_info 
>= (1, 2, 5)
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 359, in mysql_version
with self.temporary_connection():
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
return self.gen.next()
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 564, in temporary_connection
cursor = self.cursor()
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 231, in cursor
cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 204, in _cursor
self.ensure_connection()
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 170, in connect
conn_params = self.get_connection_params()
File "/root/projects/misque/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 251, in 
get_connection_params
if settings_dict['HOST'].startswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Mysql DB is working fine and i can see db and tables.
App is added in settings.py

Comment: Did you add `if settings_dict['HOST'].startswith('/'):` yourself ?

Comment: You need to post your DATABASES setting.

Comment: no i didnt add it. it is coming with python and django

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'college',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassA',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

Comment: This database setting was working with another app. I deleted that app and copied  a new app here.

Comment: Examine your `settings_dict['HOST']`. I think you'll find it's `None`. Then trace where you did get that value from. Or am I being obvious?

Comment: How can i examine settings_dict['HOST']

Comment: `settings_dict` in this context is the relevant part of the DATABASES dict you have posted already. There, HOST is clearly not None, so something must be overriding it later. Are you using something like `dj_database_url` in the settings?

Comment: This  is the error throwing python code that is coming with distrubution.              if settings_dict['HOST'].startswith('/'):
            kwargs['unix_socket'] = settings_dict['HOST']
        elif settings_dict['HOST']:
            kwargs['host'] = settings_dict['HOST']

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel Roseman . I found that there is another DATABASES config in settings. I deleted that. And now it is fine. You are the expert!, thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

I found that there is another DATABASES config in settings. I deleted that. And now it is fine

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was reading DB Credentials from env file ,it had some mistakes. when i fixed that issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

First, Note: In Windows, you might have to use “set” instead of “export” in case you are loading your Database connection variables from a .env file

In python, we have 3 different ways to store credentials and read them using Python.

1. Storing them as system variables
2. Storing them as variables in your
   virtual environment
3. Storing them in a .env file

Make sure, you choose the Most Convenient Way.

To Create a Global Environment Variable,

```
export varName=varValue
```

Ensure there are no spaces between the ‘=’. If you get an error “zsh: Bad Assignment”, it is probably caused because of space between the ‘=’.

Forexample, you can say create these variable

```
export globalSecretUser=global_uganda
export globalSecretKey = global_famitechsolutions
```

To access them

```
import os
print(os.environ) 
# This will print a dictionary with 
# all the global environment variables
```

We can use dictionary access methods to read the environment variables, i.e using .get() or [ ] As shown below

```
print(os.environ.get('globalSecretUser'))
print(os.environ.get('globalSecretKey'))
'''
global_uganda
global_famitechsolutions
'''
```

To update the environment variables, simply run the export statement again
export globalSecretUser=Updated_UgandaMountainGorillas

To remove an environment variable, we use the unset keyword

```
unset globalSecretUser
```

Important to note is that, If you try to access the variables(that do not exist) in Python, you will either get a KeyError or None depending on the method you use to access the values in the dictionary.

In my case, i was using export instead of set on my windows 7