# Django Python: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

I bumped into the error when running `python3 manage.py runserver`.

I have `mydb.py` in the project's root directory (same as `manage.py`), in order to connect to MySQL and create a database (if it does not exist).

```
project    
│
└───todo
│   │   ...
│   │   settings.py
│   │   ...
│   
└───.env
└───mydb.py
└───...
```

`mydb.py` and `settings.py` share same database configuration which is loaded from environment variables in `.env`.

`.env`:

```
ENV=DEV
SECRET_KEY='django-insecure-9#1j%osjd33e'
DB_NAME=todolist
DB_USER=user
DB_PASSWORD=12345
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
```

`settings.py`:

```py
import os
from os.path import join, dirname
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

# (1)
ENV = os.environ.get('ENV')

if ENV == 'PROD':
    env_filename = '.env.prod'
elif ENV == 'TEST':
    env_filename = '.env.test'
# elif ENV == 'DEV':
#     env_filename = '.env.dev'
else:
    env_filename = '.env'

dotenv_path = join(dirname(__file__), env_filename)
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

...

# Database
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT'),
    }
}

...
```

`mydb.py`:

```py
import mysql.connector

import os
from os.path import join, dirname
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

ENV = os.environ.get('ENV')

if ENV == 'PROD':
    env_filename = '.env.prod'
elif ENV == 'TEST':
    env_filename = '.env.test'
# elif ENV == 'DEV':
#     env_filename = '.env.dev'
else:
    env_filename = '.env'

dotenv_path = join(dirname(__file__), env_filename)
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

dataBase = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
    user = os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
    passwd = os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
)

dataBase = mysql.connector.connect()
...
```

---

Problem:

I keep getting the following error, even though `DB_HOST` is already set in `.env`.

```
...
File "/home/user/django-test/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 218, in get_connection_params
    if settings_dict["HOST"].startswith("/"):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I have checked [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith' while makemigrations with manage.py in django](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50988960/14418391) and some other related questions, but did not find any help.

Thank you

Comment: This suggests that `os.environ.get('DB_HOST')` returned `None`, because the dotenv loading somehow didn't do what you expected. Start with `print(os.environ)`…?

Comment: I tried my best to explain what I have encountered, including my own finding in other questions. Can't figure out the reason for downvotes (I literally did not copy-paste the whole codes, instead I just put relevant lines in the question). Feel free to point out unclear/missing points to summarize the question, which I should've done better

Comment: Did you try my suggestion above?

Comment: @deceze Sure, I did. It gave more or less like : `os.environ:  environ({..., 'VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT': '(.venv) ', ..., 'ENV': 'DEV', 'SECRET_KEY': 'django-insecure-9#1j%osjd33e', 'DB_NAME': 'todolist', 'DB_USER': 'user', 'DB_PASSWORD': '12345', 'DB_HOST': 'localhost', 'DB_PORT': '3306', 'TZ': 'UTC', 'RUN_MAIN': 'true'})'':`

Comment: OK. So at the *end* of your settings file, does `print(DATABASES)` output the expected database config…?

Comment: @deceze No, I mean, the output above was when I tried to load environment variables with: `load_dotenv(find_dotenv())`

When I tried to load environment variables with the code in the question, I still got nothing related to database: `os.environ:  environ({..., 'VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT': '(.venv) ', 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': 'dcrm.settings', 'TZ': 'UTC', 'RUN_MAIN': 'true'})`

Comment: Not sure you're following. The very truncated traceback you provide suggests that the `HOST` value in the `DATABASE` setting is `None`. Now, why might that be? You need to trace the steps that might lead to that and eliminate them one by one. First would be that dotenv didn't load the values into `os.environ` somehow. Second would be that you somehow overwrite `DATABASE` later in your settings file by accident. Confirm these things by printing the values to see what you have…

Comment: @deceze I can confirm that everything goes well by loading env vars with `load_dotenv(find_dotenv())`. Nevertheless, I wanted to try if it is possible by loading them with the provided code in the question, like: `dotenv_path = join(dirname(__file__), env_filename)
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely this:

```
join(dirname(__file__), env_filename)
```

This is in `todo/settings.py`, so will look for `todo/.env`.

You need to go up one more directory.

Comment: `This is in todo/settings.py, so will look for todo/.env`. Thank you, this was the key!

Comment: Otherwise this is also possible without moving `.env` into the `todo` directory: `dotenv_path = join(dirname(dirname(__file__)), '.env')` (in code in the question)

Comment: But then your `mydb.py` breaks, and it's atypical to have .env files anywhere but in the root directory.